# Excel VBA dynamic Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I need to convert the following Excel VBA formula into a Dynamic reference.  To be clear not the location of the formula, I mean the cell and sheet references with in the formula itself.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Formula = "=INDEX(DigiFull!$A$1:$DB$855,MATCH($E2,DigiFull!$A$1:$A$855,0),MATCH(M2,DigiFull!$A$1:$DB$1,1))"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the formula to the whole range at once:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("ZZ2:AAA10").Formula = "=INDEX(DigiFull!$A$1:$DB$855,MATCH($E2,DigiFull!$A$1:$A$855,0),MATCH(M2,DigiFull!$A$1:$DB$1,1))"
```

And any row/column that is not absolute will change on its own relative to the upper left cell in the target range.

Comment: I did solve this using R1C1 method:

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(DigiFull!R1C1:R" & DigiLR & "C" & DigiLC & ",MATCH(R[0]C5,DigiFull!R1C1:R" & DigiLR & "C1,0),MATCH(R[0]C" & CurrCol + 1 & ",DigiFull!R1C1:R1C" & DigiLC & ",1))"